# A RDLC subreport without subreport processing event

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting, rdlc, objectdatasource

I want to use subreport in my main report but without working or dealing with subreport processing event.

As I am making a generic form which will have the report viewer control, I just have to send a report to this control. the containing report may or may not have sub report.

Kindly suggest me any possible scenario or other reporting control which may fit in the above stated case.

View Model Code

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport report = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport();
            var reportDataSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource { Name = "AllEmployeeData", Value = EmployeeList };
            report = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport();
            report.ReportEmbeddedResource = "RDLCReport.Reports.RptEmployee.rdlc";
            report.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
            //This is the event which publish and subscribed in view to display report
            EventAggregator.GetEvent<ShowReport>().Publish(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Rpt", report } });
```

View Code

```
 private void ShowReport(Dictionary<string, object> obj)
        {
            this.ReportViewer.Report = new RDLCPrinter((Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport)obj["Rpt"]);
            this.ReportViewer.SetFitToWindowMode();
        }
```

Comment: Can describe what exactly you want to achieve ?

Comment: I am making a Generic View Form in WPF(MVVM). My this view form will get a property report and display it. The report might be single or subreport . you may consider the report a generic option.

Comment: In that case, subscribe to the subreport processing event whenever you need to ?

Comment: As all the creation of report done in ViewModel I dont want to work with subreportprocessing event on view. would you like me to put the code here

Comment: yes, please show us some code

Comment: I tried but find out that I cant avoid subreportprocessing event. Let me modify my code and take my way along with this event.

Comment: From what I understand, your RDLC report contains subreports. I don't think of any reason why it should be a problem to use the subreport processing event. If you explicitly don't want to use that event, you have to overwork your RDLC report and remove the subreport. This is possible if your data is in 1:1 relation. If it's 1:M, subreports must be used.

Comment: yes @DTs, well My plan was to avoid, but as you said and I also tried seems no way to run away from subreport processing. Will I change the scenario and now working with subreport processing event

Answer (score 2):

The subreport processing event exists because the subreport would contain data, which is relative to the data showed in the main report.

For example:

You have Ivoices report. For each invoice, there is a list of products in this invoice. You get the products for the specific invoice in the Subreport processing event.

If you don't need to use the Subreport processing event, this means that you probably don't need to use subreports.

Comment: I dont want to work with subreportprocessing event. I am looking for alternative if there is any possibilities